# Sending a file over sockets in python (Memory Error)

Tags: python, sockets, memory, out-of-memory

So I have school projects, and I am trying to read a file and then send it to the server.
the code works great but whenever I try to read a big file I am getting "Memory Error".
The error probably occurs because the size of the file, but what can I do in order to fix that?

```
msg = self.encryptor.encrypt(b'#gf ' + open(' '.join(cmd.split(' ')[1:]), 'rb').read())
```

**MemoryError**

```
   def getFile(self, cmd):
    msg = self.encryptor.encrypt(b'#gf ' + open(' '.join(cmd.split(' ')[1:]), 'rb').read())
    self.client.send(self.encryptor.encrypt(str(len(msg)).encode()))
    self.client.send(msg)
```

I am having an error in line 2.

Comment: ye, its a sign i use

Comment: What is `self.encryptor`, and does it allow *streaming* that is encoding the file in chunks?

Comment: self.encryptor is just encrypting the text (cryptography method). Even if I delete this method I get the same problem.(you can ignore it I think)

Comment: the reason Serge asked that is because if the method is capable of streaming then it doesn't need expect the entire file contents to be read in memory, IOW it doesn't expect you to use `.read` in `open(' '.join(cmd.split(' ')[1:]), 'rb').read()`

Comment: I have no idea what it means "capable of streaming", can you explain and how do I check if it capable?

Comment: from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
this is the library @python_user

Comment: I still have the problem.

Comment: Anyone? I am still facing this problem